# How to define or create customized PORT and PIN in AVR?

Tags: c++, c, avr, atmelstudio

How to define or create customized `PORT` or `PIN` in AVR?

For example, lets define a new 8 bit port called `PORTX` which consists of `PA0`(MSB), `PA1`, `PB0`, `PB1`, `PC0`, `PC1`, `PD0`, `PD1`(LSB). So that, whenever I execute the following code:

```
PORTX = 0x05;
```

It will assign `1` to both `PC1` & `PD1` and the rest being `0`.

Similarly, the following code (Assuming `PC1` & `PD1` pulled up to 5V)

```
DDRC &= ~_BV(PC1); // declaring PORTC.1 as input
DDRD &= ~_BV(PD1); // declaring PORTD.1 as input

uint8_t myValue;
myValue = PINX;
```

will assign `5` to `myValue`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply using it for reading you could do something like this

```
#define PINX     (PINA & 0x1)<<7 | (PINA & 0x2)<<6 \
                 (PINB & 0x1)<<5 | (PINB & 0x2)<<4 \
                 (PINC & 0x1)<<3 | (PINB & 0x2)<<2 \
                 (PIND & 0x1)<<1 | (PINB & 0x2)
```

If you want to set the values of `PINX` or `PORTX` you will likely want to just create a function that handles it.